# Validate form on button click in angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation, typescript, angular4-forms

As I am new in angular 4.0 and I am stuck at the validation
I am having a form which consists two fields 
here is the form

```
<form action="my-account.html" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-sm-3">User name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  placeholder="Username" required>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-3">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"  placeholder="Password" required>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Submit</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">I Forgot My Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I want to do validation on a submit button

```
**<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Submit</button>**
```

In the simplest way so how can I do it?

Comment: Might help: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 1):

Use this link and go through explains the whole scenario for validation

https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-4-forms-validation

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)" [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-sm-3">User name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="email" formControlName="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  placeholder="Username" required>
     <!-- put your validations here -->
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-3">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"  placeholder="Password" required>
        <!-- put your validations here -->
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 ">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  [disabled]="loginForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">I Forgot My Password</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

//and in you .ts file

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.profile = this.fb.group({
      userName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required]]
    })
};
```

Comment: loginForm: FormGroup; in the beginning and replace this.profile with this.loginForm

Comment: when i am trying to apply [formgroup] tag in  form control then it is showing error like template parsing error

Comment: you have to include formsModule in app.module.ts

Comment: also go through the above link i have mentioned it carries all information step by step.

Comment: even if you stuck somewhere please post

Comment: we need to import ReactiveFormsModule in app.modules to avoid this problem.

Comment: No, FormsModule from angular forms